# A Version of the Converse Implication of the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a complex vector space of dimension $2n$, and suppose $T: X \rightarrow X$ to be a linear mapping. Suppose, in addition, that we should be given a linear mapping, $a_0T^n + a_1T^{n-1} +... + a_nId$, where $a_0, ..., a_n  \in\mathbb{C}$. Presume we are informed that
$(a_0T^{n} + a_1T^{n-1} +... + a_nId)^{2n} =0$. Might it then follow that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ be given by $(a_0x^{n} + a_1x^{n-1} +... + a_n)^{2}$?

To me, this seems quite (though not entirely) remindful of the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, taken in its converse form.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of T has degree $2n$.  Why should it be equal to a polynomial of degree $2n^2$?

Comment: I have amended my enquiry.

Comment: No. Take eg $T=\mathrm{id}$, $a_0X^n+a_1X^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n=(X-1)(X-2)\ldots (X-n)$.

Comment: @V.Elizabeth Does the other exponent $2n$ also change or is it still $2n$?

Comment: No, it should be $2n$.

Answer (score 1):

The basic conflict here is that matrix identities can only give information about the *minimal* polynomial, but the characteristic polynomial is neither uniquely determined by the minimal polynomial nor vice versa.  Yes, the two polynomials must share the same complex roots, but the multiplicities are nearly independent of one another, save for the obvious fact that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial.

The fact that some $p(T) = 0$ only tells you that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is a divisor of $p$, but it could be a very low-degree divisor that fails to give much information about the characteristic polynomial of $T$.  For example, if $T = 0$ then any polynomial with $a_n = 0$ satisfies the condition, but obviously the characteristic polynomial can’t be simultaneously equal to all possible values of $(a_0x^n + \cdots + a_{n-1}x)^2$.